# OpenCL Cholesky Decomposition

Tags: algorithm, opencl, blas

I implemented the following Cholesky decomposition algorithm using OpenCL. The code is exhibiting random behavior. It matches the cpu output only some times. Can someone please help me to figure out what is wrong with my implementation.

Here is the algorithm:

```
procedure CHOLESKY(A)
int i, j, k;
for k := 0 to n − 1 do /* 1st loop */
    /* Obtain the square root of the diagonal element. */
    A[k, k] := A[k, k];

    for j := k + 1 to n − 1 do /* 2nd loop */
    /* The division step. */
        A[k, j] := A[k, j]/A[k, k];
    end for

    for i := k + 1 to n − 1 do /* 3rd loop */
        for j := i to n − 1 do /* 4th loop */
            /* The elimination step. */
            A[i, j] := A[i, j] - A[k, i] × A[k, j];

        end for
    end for
end for
```

**Methodology to parallelize the above algorithm:**

From the algorithm, the elimination step is the most expensive. So I have the outermost loop
in the host code, and I call the kernel within the loop. A single run of the kernel basically
corresponds to a single iteration of the 3rd loop. Therefore, I launch (n-1 )- (k+1) + 1 work groups. The number of work items within a workgroup is set to n/2. The 2nd for loop is also computed within the kernel, but I allow only the first workgroup to do it.

**RELEVANT HOST CODE**

```
// for a 10 X 10 matrix, MATRIX_SIZE = 10
localWorkSize[0] = MATRIX_SIZE/2;
stride = MATRIX_SIZE/2;
cl_event             event;

for(k = 0; k < MATRIX_SIZE; k++)
{

    int isize = (MATRIX_SIZE-1) - (k+1) + 1;
    int num_blocks = isize;
    if(num_blocks <= 0)
            num_blocks = 1;
    globalWorkSize[0] = num_blocks * WA/2;

    errcode = clSetKernelArg(clKernel, 0, sizeof(int), (void *)&k);
    errcode |= clSetKernelArg(clKernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&d_A);
    errcode |= clSetKernelArg(clKernel, 2, sizeof(int), (void *)&stride);

    errcode = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(clCommandQueue,
          clKernel, 1, NULL, globalWorkSize,
          localWorkSize, 0, NULL, &event);

    OpenCL_CheckError(errcode, "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel");
    clFinish(clCommandQueue);
}
```

**KERNEL CODE**

```
__kernel void
batchedCholesky(__global float *U, int k, int stride)
{

    int tx = get_global_id(0);
    unsigned int j;
    unsigned int num_rows = MATRIX_SIZE;

    if(tx==0)
    {
            // Take the square root of the diagonal element
            U[k * num_rows + k] = sqrt(U[k * num_rows + k]);
    }
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    int offset = (k+1); //From original loop
    int jstart = get_local_id(0) + offset;
    int jstep = stride;
    int jtop = num_rows - 1;

    int jbottom = (k + 1);
    //Do work for this i iteration
    //Division step
    if(get_group_id(0) == 0)
    {
            for(j = jstart; (j >= jbottom) && (j <= jtop); j+=jstep)
            {
                    U[k * num_rows + j] /= U[k * num_rows + k]; // Division step
            }
    }
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    j = 0;

    int i = get_group_id(0) + (k+1);

    offset = i;

    jstart = get_local_id(0) + offset;

    jbottom = i;

    for( j = jstart; j >= jbottom && j <= jtop; j += jstep)

            U[i * num_rows + j] -= U[k * num_rows + i] * U[k * num_rows + j];

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);   
}
```

Comment: I see three `CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE` barriers but no usage of local memory. Did you mean `CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE`? Or is this not the entire relevant code?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It should be CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE.

Answer (score 1):

Not all of your work items execute at the same time, they may run in batches. So your code running prior to `CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE` *won't include every value*. That may be the source of your errors.

If you require global synchronization, use multiple kernels.

Comment: I am unable to find any examples showing how to use multiple kernels. Can you please provide one.

Comment: It is fine. I got it working. Your observation regarding global synchronization is correct. Thanks.